# Spring MVC redirect returning RedirectView doesn't allow src image link to load

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect

When Spring MVC does a redirect, should the page redirected to be able to process embedded src attributes that hit a server to fetch an image, as if loading a page for the first time? It works correctly when accessed via a link on a web page.  Is redirect different than loading a new page via a link?  My understanding was that redirect should load a page completely, resolving all references, similar to the way it does when navigating to it via a link on a web page.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP response known as a **redirect** looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.yourhost.com/some-page
Connection: close
```

That's it. When your browser receives this response, it will send a new HTTP GET request to the URI in the `Location` header.

Your error is somewhere else.

Comment: You're right. It was somewhere else.  Some javascript wasn't getting fired on load for unrelated reasons.